# How can I check if a class object exists in a C++ set?

Tags: c++, class, set

I am trying to write a piece of code that allows the user to input a certain amount of names, and then checks to see if any objects that contain those names exist in the set.
What I want is for the program to take the names entered by the user, loop through the set and see if the name exists in any of the object elements, and then print to the command line whether the name exists or not.

For some reason, it prints "Name does not exist in set" for each element in the set even if the name exists in the set. How can I get this to check properly? Also, how can I get it to only print the "does not exist" message once even if the check fails multiple times before finding (or not finding) a match?

My code so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class Name {
   public:
      Name();
      Name(string n);
      bool operator<(Name right)const; 
      string get_name()const;
   private:
      string name;             
};

Name::Name(){}

Name::Name(string n)
{
   name = n;
}

bool Name::operator<(Name right)const
{
      bool result = true;
      return result;
}

string Name::get_name()const
{
      return "Name name is: " + name + "\n";
}

int main(){

set<Name>NamesSet;
NamesSet.insert(Name("Patrick Star"));
NamesSet.insert(Name("Jason"));
NamesSet.insert(Name("Bob Marl"));
NamesSet.insert(Name("Greg"));
set<Name>::iterator pos; 


int numjobs;
string cusname;
cout << "Number of names to enter:" << endl;
cin >> numjobs;
cin.ignore();
if (numjobs != 0 || numjobs > 0) {
   for (int i = 0; i != numjobs; i++)
   {
      cout << endl;
      cout << "Name " << i+1 << ": " << endl;
      getline(cin, cusname);

      for (pos = NamesSet.begin(); pos != NamesSet.end(); pos++) 
      {
         if (NamesSet.count((*pos).get_name()))
         {
            cout << (*pos).get_name() << " exists in set";
            break;
         }
         else 
         {
            cout << "Name does not exist in set";
         }
      }
   }
}

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use e.g. [`std::find` (with an appropriate comparison operator) or `std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: Your `class Name` doesn't seem to do anything a `std::string` doesn't do. Why not just use `std::string` instead?

Comment: I agree with Galik, but if you are using this Name class, then pass Name to the operator< by const reference or you make copy every time. Also your get_name doesn't return the original name but adds some text, did you take into account that? If get_name is changed just to return name directly, you can change its return type to const reference.

Comment: The name class will have more stuff in the future, that's why I want this working with objects instead of strings first. I actually didn't take into account get_name() returns more than the name, must be one of those days >.>, I've tried some of the code in the answers but it still wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change these :

```
bool Name::operator<(const Name& right)const
{
      return (this->name < right.name);
}

string Name::get_name()const
{
      return name;
}
```

This would be a working sample :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class Name {
   public:
      Name();
      Name(string n);
      bool operator<(const Name& right)const; 
      string get_name()const;
   private:
      string name;             
};

Name::Name(){}

Name::Name(string n)
{
   name = n;
}

bool Name::operator<(const Name& right)const
{
      return (this->name < right.name);
}

string Name::get_name()const
{
      return name;
}

int main()
{

set<Name>NamesSet;
NamesSet.insert(Name("Patrick Star"));
NamesSet.insert(Name("Jason"));
NamesSet.insert(Name("Bob Marl"));
NamesSet.insert(Name("Greg"));
set<Name>::iterator pos; 

string cusname = "Greg";

if ( NamesSet.count(cusname) == 1 )
{
    cout << cusname << " exists in set"<<endl;
}
else 
{
    cout<<"Nanda!";
}

   return 0;
}
```

http://codepad.org/kg9gtSsX

Comment: Working perfectly, no freezing or anything :) thanks for the help!

Comment: Why would you use a getter? `operator<` is a member function: it has complete access to private member variables.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Name::operator<` is incorrect. It returns `true` always, which means that the `set` will always believe two `Name` objects to compare unequal.

Instead, compare your name strings by returning `this->name < right.name`, and you should see the right behaviour from your `set`.

(Incidentally, your `operator<` should take a `const Name &` for efficiency's sake).

Comment: I tried this with both "return this.name < right.name" and "return this->name < right->name" and both through errors. How can I implement this correctly? I don't even use this in main() so why is this needed?

Comment: @Ultimabuster: `std::set` uses `operator<` to compare elements. It therefore requires a correct implementation to function properly.

Comment: @Ultimabuster: also I had a syntax error oops, try with `this->name < right.name`. (`this` is a pointer, `right` is an object).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'm still getting a "base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Name'" error when I try this. I can't figure out how to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the code is wrong for starters

```
  for (pos = NamesSet.begin(); pos != NamesSet.end(); pos++) <-------- count does this for you
  {
     if (NamesSet.count((*pos).get_name())) <------ you check the whole set to see if it is in itself
     {
        cout << (*pos).get_name() << " exists in set";
        break;
     }
     else 
     {
        cout << "Name does not exist in set";
     }
  }
```

This should be better, replace the above with this:

```
     if (NamesSet.count(cusname))
     {
        cout << cusname << " exists in set";
        break;
     }
     else 
     {
        cout << "Name does not exist in set";
     }
```

Comment: I think I got the operator< working thanks to the all the others help, but when I run this code, it gives the "not found" message correctly, but freezes/crashes the application when it finds a valid match.

Answer (score 1):

You need this

```
bool operator< (const Name& right) {
    return name < right.name;
};
```

However, in this case, you may directly use the string, instead of Name.

Comment: I think this is working now, at least it doesn't through any errors when compiling, thanks! But now my program is freezing when it finds a match. :/